# Visual Studio - Solution with a WPF and NodeJS Server

Tags: c#, node.js, wpf, visual-studio

I am new to VS, but I have experience wit Python, NodeJS and stuff like this. I do have problably a simple question just for my understanding. If I create a WPF-C# project and do the standard stuff, design a window, make some code behind etc...
Would it be possible to add a NodeJS project, f.e. a web express webserver and deploy it into one bundle for the customer?

The question came up, because the customer does have a windows application and wants to add my NodeJS functioanality. And do not want to have 2 Applications which he has to roll out and update.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean add NodeJs code in WPF project? or add the function which implement by NodeJS?

Comment: basically I want to add a NodeJS App which starts with the WPF Solution. So the user starts still the WPF solution but in the background the NodeJS App starts a express server which is responsible for API-requests to trigger functions and get data. I already realized that this is not possible in the binaries. I found another solution which I will post here as my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of my requirements I refactored the WPF-Solution to an electron application, where I implemented all my NodeJS code behind. I was very surprised that the electron app is much more faster. And after a while of reading the docs its very simple to deploy and push to GitHub and do autoUpdates. Even deployment on Mac was incredible easy.

Sounds like commercial, but its indeed true and I am happy with electron :-D

The only hard way I had was to redesign the XAML WPF to HTML and CSS. Still pain in the a** in my opinion.